# comparing two columns and replace NaN with numbers

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, data-cleaning

```
for i in range(len(df1)-1):
    if (df1['overall_rating'][i]==np.nan) and (df1['recommended'][i]==0):
        df1['overall_rating']=df1['overall_rating'][i].replace(np.nan,1)
    else:
        df1['overall_rating']
print(df1['overall_rating'])
```

I am comparing overall rating columns and recommended column in a pandas dataframe. If both column values happens to be true then i should replace nan in rating column to be 1 . But I am not getting answer as well error.Anyone please let me know where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for set `1` by 2 conditions, for test missing values is used [`Series.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html) function:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'overall_rating':[np.nan,2,4,np.nan],
                   'recommended':[0,0,1,1]})

df1.loc[df1['overall_rating'].isna() & (df1['recommended']==0), 'overall_rating'] = 1
print (df1)
   overall_rating  recommended
0             1.0            0
1             2.0            0
2             4.0            1
3             NaN            1
```

Comment: Hi Jezrael, Thanks for your reply. But I am getting  AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'isna'

Comment: @VIgneshNagaraj - solution is outside loop? do you remove `for i in range(len(df1)-1):` ? If yes, try to change `isna` to `isnull`

Comment: @ Jezrael.Again I am getting the same error.AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'isnull'  .Please  check my code. Please correct if I am wrong.                                                                                                m = df1['overall_rating'][i].isnull() & (df1['recommended'][i]==0)
for i in range(len(df1)-1):
    if m:
        df1['overall_rating'] = np.where(m, df1['overall_rating'][i].fillna(1), df1['overall_rating'])

Comment: @VIgneshNagaraj - Unfortunately you are wrong, because no loop is necessary here. Check changed answer with data, also it is simplify a bit.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me. It worked. Could you please explain how it works.